# JS Make deep copy of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, deep-copy

Is there any way I can make a deep copy of a variable? (NOT object). Example:

```
var a = ["String", "string"];
var b = a;

b.splice(1, 1);

b = a;
```

In my example, `a` isnt supposed to change, I want to use it later for restoring `b`. (As showed in code above).

I understand that `=` just makes a new reference, hence the question: is there any other way I can make a deep copy instead of a reference?

Want to note that I can't be using any library, I've found answers suggesting jQuery and such, but I cannot use this.

Comment: It's only objects in javascript (arrays are objects too) that gets references to each other. All other variable types are new variables.

Comment: @RickardElimää Sorry, the example was really poor, fixed now

Answer (score 2):

Have you tested your code? `Numbers` and other primitives are copied, not referenced.

```js
var a = 1;
var b = a;
console.log(`a is ${a}`);
console.log(`b is ${b}`);
b++;
console.log(`a is ${a} (no change)`);
console.log(`b is ${b}`);
```

After your edit with a different example:

```js
var a = ["foo", "bar"];
var b = a.slice(); // array copy
console.log(`a is ${a}`);
console.log(`b is ${b}`);
b.splice(1, 1);
console.log(`a is ${a} (not changed)`);
console.log(`b is ${b}`);
b = a;
```

Comment: That's my bad, really poor example, in my case I'm handling string arrays, which I have tested

Comment: @Chaost An array is not a primitive but an object.

Comment: @Chaost Well a string array (array of strings?) is just an object, so refer to deep-copying arrays.

Comment: @AurelBílý oh didn't notice the `var b = a;`

Comment: Try by this line: var b = Object.assign([], a);